# Outlook Web Access not working after Office Web Apps Setup

Tags: windows, exchange, outlook-web-app, web-applications

I have a Windows Server 2012 running Exchange 2013. Everything works smoothly until I install the WebAppsServer to enable WebReady Document Viewing in Outlook Web App, so users can preview Excel and Word documents.

I run the setup and afterwards, following the insructions [HERE](http://www.msexchange.org/articles-tutorials/exchange-server-2013/management-administration/exchange-2013-office-web-apps-server-integration.html) and [HERE](http://michaelvh.wordpress.com/tag/web-ready-document-viewing/) I put `New-OfficeWebAppsFarm -InternalUrl “https://mydomain” –CertificateName “mycert” –EditingEnabled`

I get the warning to only set EditingEnabled if I have the right licenses. So I say "n" to stop and I run `New-OfficeWebAppsFarm -InternalUrl “https://mydomain” –CertificateName “mycert”` without editing.

Unfortunately instead of working WebAppss after some computation I get the error that the Office Web Apps Service failed to start. Now comes the bad thing:

My Outlook Webapp is broken and won't work.

What emergency measures can I take to get OWA back and running asap?

Comment: I have taken a screenshot of the error in the protocol http://oi42.tinypic.com/soxo44.jpg